# Dax - how to get average value per day where column x value is y?

Tags: syntax, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to figure out how to get average value per day where type is for example of type "Test". This would show
the average value for all rows wich has the type as "Test" and the average of that same day. So all days would 
probably get different average values. How would this be done in Dax syntax? Below is a combination of sql
and normal text which might help explain what im trying to archieve.

select average Values per day from mytable where type = test

I'm providing an example table that might make it easier to understand, it's a quite simple question but I 
fail to find information on how to solve it, any help or input is highly appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the dataset to calculate the test value average.

```
AverageTestValues =
CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( myTable[Values] ), FILTER ( myTable, [Type] = "Test" ) )
```

This expression calculates the test values average in a given context. If you use the measure in a total context you will get the average of all rows type `Test`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me the average values of all types of type test. How would i use this combined with the average depending on the date(day)? Since now it takes the average of all so all dates have the same average value

Comment: @Mattias, It depends on the visualization and columns you are using on it. For example, if you use a table and add `Date` column and `AverageTestValues` it will give you the average of every date which type is equal to `Test`. Add details about the visualization you are after for further help.

Comment: Accepting, i think this one did it